# How can i speed up this loop in R?

Tags: r, lm

```
set.seed(155656494)

#setting parameter values
n<-500
sdu<-25
beta0<-40
beta1<-12

# Running the simulation again

# create the x variable outside the loop since it’s fixed in  
# repeated sampling 
x2 <- floor(runif(n,5,16))

# set the number of iterations for your simulation (how many values 
# of beta1 will be estimated)
nsim2 <- 10000000

# create a vector to store the estimated values of beta1 
vbeta2 <- numeric(nsim2) 

# create a loop that produces values of y, regresses y on x, and  
# stores the OLS estimate of beta1

for (i in 1:nsim2) {
  y2 <- beta0 + beta1*x2 + 0.2*x2 + rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=sdu)  
  model2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)   
  vbeta2[i] <- coef(model2)[[2]] 
}

mean(vbeta2)
```

The above is a simple linear regression model that has 10 million iterations. I looking for help with speeding up the loop. This code basically runs as y2 <- beta0 + beta1*x2 + 0.2*x2 + rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=sdu), which will then be used to calculate the mean of vbeta2

Comment: You could parallelize it using e.g. the foreach library

Comment: `lm` is already pretty quick. 10 million iterations just takes a long time. Even if a whole 500-element regression took 1 microsecond the loop would still take 10 seconds. Why would you need 10 million iterations. The final result would presumably be the same to within 5 decimal places with "only" 1 million iterations.

Comment: if you only need the coefficient, `lm.fit` or `.lm.fit` should be faster. also you could generate all of your random data at once

Answer (score 0):

You could use `profvis` to determine where is processor time spent:

```
library(profvis)

profvis({
  set.seed(155656494)
  
  #setting parameter values
  n<-500
  sdu<-25
  beta0<-40
  beta1<-12
  
  # Running the simulation again
  
  # create the x variable outside the loop since it’s fixed in  
  # repeated sampling 
  x2 <- floor(runif(n,5,16))
  
  # set the number of iterations for your simulation (how many values 
  # of beta1 will be estimated)
  nsim2 <- 1000
  
  # create a vector to store the estimated values of beta1 
  vbeta2 <- numeric(nsim2) 
  
  # create a loop that produces values of y, regresses y on x, and  
  # stores the OLS estimate of beta1
  
  for (i in 1:nsim2) {
    y2 <- beta0 + beta1*x2 + 0.2*x2 + rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=sdu)  
    model2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)   
    vbeta2[i] <- coef(model2)[[2]] 
  }
  
  mean(vbeta2)
 
})
```

The result shows that most of the time is spent evaluating the linear regression model :
[image]

As suggested by @maarvd, you could paralellize to speed this up. However parallelizing each single calculation won't be efficient because one calculation is too fast (~0.5 ms), so you'll have to distribute chuncks of many thousand calculations per worker. I agree with @Allan Cameron, is this worth the effort?

Comment: The linear regression itself can be sped up by stripping parts of the code, as has been illustrated in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html#t-test) and [the article cited there](http://stat-computing.org/newsletter/issues/scgn-18-1.pdf).